# How can I access extra columns in SQLAlchemy a many-to-many relationship with an association object (without an association proxy)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I am defining a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy in which I use an association object between two models, and I need to be able to access data in the extra columns as if it was part of the model in the collection

I'm building this under the constraint where I can't use an association proxy, and must use `relationship` to define the collection

A simple version of the schema I made so far

```
class Blueprint(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blueprints'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    spec = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
    parts = relationship('parts', secondary='blueprint_parts', lazy='dynamic')


class BlueprintParts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blueprint_parts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    blueprint_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('blueprints.id'), primary_key=True)
    part_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parts.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String)

class Parts:
    __tablename__ = 'parts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    vendor = Column(String)
```

A brief example of how I'd like to use this relationship (Autocommit is enabled)

```
b = Blueprint.query(id=42).one_or_none()
for p in b.parts:
    print(p.extra_data)
    print(p.name)
    if condition:
        p.extra_data = "blah"
```

Currently, none of the objects in `p.parts` contain `extra_data`. Only the attributes defined in `Parts`

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  Specifically why you do not want to use the association proxy ?  Also it seems that you'd really want an explicit [association object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) for the example you have given anyways.

Comment: @IanWilson I can't use an association proxy because our system has a lot of complex logic in place for handling relationships since we never anticipated the need for an association proxy. So adding a refactor would take too long.

Thanks for the link! It looks like I got too tangled in other association object usages to notice that I can get the behavior I want by making a relationship between BlueprintParts and Blueprint, instead of BlueprintParts to Parts

Comment: @NickErokhin sounds like you found the solution? It would be great if you could post the solution to your problem as an answer.

Comment: @tgig thanks for the reminder, I answered

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my desired behavior with a few workarounds in the schema and code

```
class Blueprint(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blueprints'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    spec = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
    blueprint_parts = relationship('BlueprintParts', lazy='dynamic')


class BlueprintParts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blueprint_parts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    blueprint_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('blueprints.id'), primary_key=True)
    part_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parts.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String)
    part = relationship('Parts', lazy='joined')

class Parts:
    __tablename__ = 'parts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    vendor = Column(String)
```

The code then works as follows

```
b = Blueprint.query(id=42).one_or_none()
part = Parts(name='some_name', vendor='some_vendor')
blueprint_part = BlueprintParts(extra_data='something', part=part)
b.blueprint_parts.append(blueprint_part)

for p in b.blueprint_parts:
    print(p.extra_data)
    # Access part via p.part
    print(p.part.name)
```